# JUnit tests: How to "inherit" Spring application context without extending base test class?

Tags: spring, junit, junit5, spring-test

My tests of a Spring application are written using JUnit 4. To ease writing of JUnit tests and reduce repetitive code, I use a base class (`AbstractDaoTest`) that defines a basic Spring application context using annotation `@ContextConfiguration(classes = …)`:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDbConf.class)
public abstract class AbstractDaoTest {
    ...
}
```

Subclasses extend the application context by defining extra annotation `ContextConfiguration(…)` with additional classes:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeExtraBean.class)
public class SomeTestClass extends AbstractDaoTest {
    ...
}
```

JUnit 5 came with the modern approach "composition is better than inheritance".

I like the idea so I tried to avoid inheritance by defining a composed annotation:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDbConf.class)
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface DaoTest { }
```

… and using the annotation on a test class:

```java
@DaoTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExtraBeanClass.class)
public class SomeTest {
    ...
}
```

But when I execute it, it seems that the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation causes the application context to be shadowed/overwritten, i.e. the context defined by annotation `@DaoTest` is not used.

What is the correct approach? Is it possible to achieve the goal using JUnit 5 extension?

I searched the internet and read several articles about JUnit 5 extensions and JUnit 5 in general but I couldn't find the answer in any of them.